# Parse value only from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

An API returns a string of text that looks like this (xxx used for security):

```
{"xxx":{"xxx":{"xxx":{"xxx":{"results":[{"latest.GigabytesIngested":12641.824682336}]}}}}}
```

If I do this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.results[0]);
```

I get this, which is fine:

```
{ 'latest.GigabytesIngested': 12641.82487968 }
```

My problem is I only want to grab the number. The below attempt doesn't work, maybe because there's a dot in the key name, or maybe because I'm just doing it wrong?

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.results[0].latest.GigabytesIngested);
```

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(body).xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.results[0]["latest.GigabitesIngested"])`

Comment: Spell bytes correctly and post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the period in the key is the problem. You need to use an alternate way to reference the key.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.results[0]["latest.GigabytesIngested"]);
```

or

```
var result = JSON.parse(body).xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.results[0];
var lgi = result["latest.GigabytesIngested"];
console.log(lgi);
```

Comment: You even seem to have just copied my comment, because you have the same spelling mistake ...

Comment: @JimmyD Yes, a comment cant be accepted as answer. But copying someone else's comment (inclusive typo) as own answer is *VERY* discouraged ...

Comment: I see no way of accepting a comment as an answer. So if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @JimmyD: There is no way of accepting a comment as answer. But tbh: I don't really care about reputation that much that I'd post an anwer to a question that probably has been asked hundrets of time on SO (I'm just to lazy to search for a duplicate). That's why I just put it in a comment. But I also really dont like, someone else trying to take the credit for my original comment ...

Comment: @derpirscher I read the question and was ready to give the same answer before I read your comment.  I upvoted your comment anyway.  A comment is not an answer.  Next time enter the answer if you want credit for it.  I also included alternate syntax to elaborate on how it worked.

Comment: @JanineWhite You were ready to give the answer without reading my comment, and 
coincidentally you included the very same typo in your answer as I did in my comment? And as I already said, this question has been asked many times on SO, so it should be  marked as a duplicate, instead of giving an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

@derpirscher answered correctly in a comment:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).data.actor.account.nrql.results[0]['latest.GigabytesIngested']);
```